# BlackBerry Java development setup using Maven and NetBeans

Tags: maven-2, blackberry, netbeans

I've developed a couple of BlackBerry applications. Is there a POM file for creating these projects in [Maven 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#History)?

Ideally I would like to have this setup:

Linux + Maven 2 + Netbeans

That is, something like

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=blackberry-stub`

`mvn clean install` would build the cod files **and sign them**.

`mvn compile:execute` would start the emulator.